# Connecting to IBM / ISPF from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, mainframe, ispf

I want to connect to IBM mainframe thru VB.net and run jobs present in mainframe directly through VB.net and view the output back....
Can any one please help how to connect to IBM mainframe and run jobs directly through vb.net....

Comment: This is entirely dependent on your mainframe and what facilities it makes available to the rest of your enterprise.

Comment: We are using IBM mainframe and ISPF as a interface for mainframe

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Do you want to submit JCL from Windows, or submit JCL located in PDS members stored on the mainframe?

Comment: i just want to submit JCL's stored in PDS member in mainframe....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you are not looking to duplicate the functionality of [ISPF GUI mode](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=interface-running-in-gui-mode).

One method would be to use FTP directly to the JES internal reader as discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323538/how-to-submit-jcl-on-ibm-zos-through-java-web-app).  It is possible that the mainframe security folks will disallow this, I know mine did.

Another method would be to [screen scrape](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=screen%20scrape%203270&submit=search) ISPF.

Instead of screen scraping ISPF, you could use the [submit](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=subcommands-submit-command) command in [TSO](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=zos-tsoe) and run [SDSF](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=sdsf) in TSO to retrieve your output.  You could also write [Rexx](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=guide-using-sdsf-rexx-programming-language) or [Java](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=guide-using-sdsf-java-programming-language) to run on the mainframe to give you your output in a form you desire instead of having your VB code conscious of the ISPF and/or SDSF panels.

You could use a [CICS web service](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.6?topic=applications-developing-web) that submits batch jobs via the [SPOOL](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.6?topic=summary-spoolopen-output) API, retrieving the results might be more of a challenge.  You might have to store the output in a z/OS Unix file and retrieve it from there.

Comment: All JCL's are stored in PDS member of mainframe...i just want to trigger the job from VB.net...In fact duplicating the functionality of ISPF GUI.....Also i want the result(return code) of the job back in VB.net...

Comment: Along with the TSO SUBMIT command, look at the relatively new SDSF REXX interface.